# How to replace "@[" anywhere in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

My question is  about regular expressions. I want to  replace `"@["` anywhere in the string. Tried with `[@[]` expression, but it's not working, because it replaces `@` anywhere in the string.

Comment: '[' is special character in RegEx - does it even work with such pattern?

Comment: Can you create a small example of the source you are currently using to reproduce the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Could you provide some examples? Some set of strings showing what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
/@\[/g
```

```js
function replace(str){
    return str.replace(/@\[/g, '');
}


console.log(replace('@[]'));
console.log(replace('abcd@[absd]ahah@[ahah'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "Microsoft" with "W3Schools" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">Visit Microsoft! @[</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/@\[/g, "W3Schools");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```